# Valuable inventory: Scraped content (Admob)

Tags: android, admob, ads, facebook-ads

Recently I have got a notice from Admob for one of my app & policy violation is

```
**Valuable inventory: Scraped content**

As stated in our Program policies, we may not show Google ads on pages or apps with little or no value and/or excessive advertising to the user. This includes pages or apps that are scraping or rewriting of content from other sources without adding value. Please see Google’s Webmaster quality guidelines for thin content with little or no added value for more information.

For more information, review the following resources:

Policy tips for creating high quality sites (part 1)
Policy tips for creating high quality sites (part 2)
Webmaster quality guidelines
AdSense Program policies
```

Is it okay if I remove Admob ads(Google) & display Facebook ads?

Below is my app
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.freeyourself.amitabhbachchanhits

Answer (score 0):

Some videos of your app are blocked, you have to go to Youtube app to watch them...
I guess this is a motive to that, so even on Facebook this problem is going to continue.
Remove those videos and build a privacy policy to your app disclaiming you do not own any of them. You can find some apps to build a privacy policy on Play Store.

Also, after the new Android 11 launch, you need to declare in your ANDROID MANIFEST.xml the API's that your app is using, just add:

```
<queries>
   <intent>
     <action android:name="com.google.android.youtube.api.service.START"/>
   </intent>
</queries>
```

Comment: Please return me if it works or how you solved it

Comment: I will let you know once its fixed